# Accomplishment feedback when reviewing flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

The [Flagged Posts list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) filters out posts that I have already completed. (Specifically, if I reinforce or disagree with the flags on that post, then that post comes off of the list).

Can the flag counter do the same? It is pretty boring to review posts, and the counter never goes down.

I know the count doesn't really go down from the moderator point of view, but from my point of view, I appear to be losing ground no matter how many posts I review.

[image]

Comment: My OCD hates this.  I cannot handle the fact that the counter doesn't drop when I am reviewing.

Comment: -1 for non-freehand circles ;)

Comment: Try being a moderator. Review 10 flags - refresh page - counter only drops by 1.

Comment: At least it didn't *go up* by 1.

Comment: Ah, you recently acquired the 10K privileges.  Yeah, you didn't count on *that* reward, did you?  It is voluntary, nobody forces you to actually look at this cr8p.

Comment: @Undo, How's that! :D

Comment: @animuson, For me, they never go down, unless the moderator is working on flags also at the same time.

Comment: @Uphill, With comments like animuson's, I'd be glad to help with flag reviewing.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Way better! :D